# Image version on Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm making an album section and after the user uploads the images, carrierwave is making some versions like `:thumb` and `:full`.

When showing all the albums I get the first image of the album and display as the album cover. The thing is, I'm having to resize the thumb image and it gets ugly, I'd like to know if I can make a version (`:cover`) only of the first image uploaded so I can call this version when showing albums, but only the first image, so I don't have to make this version for all the images since I'll just be using the first one.

Comment: You can do [conditional versions](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#conditional-versions)